# How to randomly sort list items with exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently have this code that randomly sorts list items:

```
array.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
```

I want one of the elements to always be the last. How to do it?

Comment: `one of the elements` ..Which one?

Comment: Perform the sort, then move whatever item to the end by appending/pushing it back to the array/collection again.

Comment: you can first exclude this element and after sorting again include in the array using append()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
array = ["a", "b", "the last", "c", "d"];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (b == "the last") ? -1 :
        ((a == "the last") ?  1 :
         (0.5 - Math.random()));
});
document.write(array);
```

How it works:

- the comparator returns positive for "shift a to the right" and negative for "shift b to the right"
- yours works, because it randomized these answers
- for keeping the element "the last" on the right side, the comparator must behave accordingly